# multiple inner join not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, join

so i got this query that is fully working in mysql phpmyadmin but its not working when i use it in a php file.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM services_package 
  JOIN service_in_package 
    ON services_package.id = service_in_package.package_id 
  JOIN itv 
    ON service_in_package.service_id = itv.id 
  JOIN tv_genre 
    ON itv.tv_genre_id = tv_genre.id  
 WHERE services_package.id  = 25
```

any idea why?

i already tried it multiple times and the problem is somewhere here:

```
INNER JOIN tv_genre ON itv.tv_genre_id = tv_genre.id
```

this is the php code:

```
    $sql = "
    SELECT * 
      FROM services_package 
      JOIN service_in_package 
        ON services_package.id = service_in_package.package_id 
      JOIN itv 
        ON service_in_package.service_id = itv.id 
      JOIN tv_genre 
        ON itv.tv_genre_id = tv_genre.id 
     WHERE services_package.id = 25
    "; 

$rows = array();

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
     while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;

    }

echo json_encode($rows);
```

}
okay, so i get no errors. even with errors turned on.  the loop is looping 8 times (which is correct cause it should return 8 rows) but it has no output.

it actually is working when :

```
 INNER JOIN tv_genre ON itv.tv_genre_id = tv_genre.id
```

is removed. im so confused.

UPDATE:
i checked the rows in phpmyadmin and noticed that multiple rows had the same name 'ID' and thought it could create a conflict in the conversion to JSON so i made a new query:

```
        SELECT itv.id AS channel_id, 
tv_genre.id AS genre_id, 
services_package.id AS service_package_id, 
itv.name AS channel_name, 
itv.descr AS channel_description, 
services_package.type AS channel_type, 
itv.number, itv.censored, 
itv.cmd AS channel_source, 
tv_genre.title AS genre_name, 
itv.logo
FROM services_package
JOIN service_in_package ON services_package.id = service_in_package.package_id
JOIN itv ON service_in_package.service_id = itv.id
JOIN tv_genre ON itv.tv_genre_id = tv_genre.id
WHERE services_package.id =25
```

which is working in phpmyadmin and not working in a php file :/

var_dump result(changed the channel_source for obvious reasons):

```
array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "846" ["genre_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(8) "HAC 2 HD" ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(1) "5" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(45) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(8) "Englisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" } array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "845" ["genre_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(8) "HAC 1 HD" ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(1) "4" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(44) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(8) "Englisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" } array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "831" ["genre_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(9) "HAC 3 HD " ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(1) "6" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(45) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(8) "Englisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" } array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "829" ["genre_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(8) "HAC SD 3" ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(1) "3" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(39) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(8) "Englisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" } array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "828" ["genre_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(8) "HAC SD 2" ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(1) "2" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(39) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(8) "Englisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" } array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "814" ["genre_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(13) "Go To Luxe.TV" ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(2) "23" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(41) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(8) "Englisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" } array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "808" ["genre_id"]=> string(1) "8" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(16) "Nature & Animaux" ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(2) "10" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(36) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(11) "Französisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" } array(11) { ["channel_id"]=> string(3) "807" ["genre_id"]=> string(1) "8" ["service_package_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["channel_name"]=> string(8) "HAC SD 1" ["channel_description"]=> string(0) "" ["channel_type"]=> string(2) "tv" ["number"]=> string(1) "1" ["censored"]=> string(1) "0" ["channel_source"]=> string(39) "http://test.com" ["genre_name"]=> string(11) "Französisch" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" }
```

the only thing i can think of right now is that something goes wrong while converting the result to JSON

Comment: If it does not work in PHP then it would be better to show the PHP code.

Comment: What sort of not working is it?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @LornaMitchell blank page, no errors in php. in mysql i get the result i want. in php i just get no result. but the query is being executed. whenever i delete the 'problem bit' it actually returns data

Comment: Here's a usefult tip: NEVER  use evil `SELECT *`

Comment: The most obvious difference between both environments is the extra `if($result->num_rows > 0){}` check in PHP. Even if you really need it (do you?) you should comment it out for diagnostic.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Surely the most obvious difference, is an environment that's easily confused by duplicated column names, versus one that isn't!

Comment: @Strawberry To explain lack of output, that's my candidate (together with disabled error reporting, but that belongs to configuration more than code)

Comment: is not working for `INNER JOIN tv_genre ON itv.tv_genre_id = tv_genre.id` so there is no match for that join, that's why it is not working.

Comment: @JorgeCampos but in the mysql phpmyadmin its working. and its 100% connected to the same database.

Comment: We work on facts. The fact is: if it works without that join it means: 1 - You are in a different databases (double check it); 2 - you are using different users to connect (one that may not have select grant to the tv_genre table); so to rule out those... do a `select distinct itv.tv_genre_id from your current query without that join` and output it and do a `select id from tv_genre` and output it, compare.

Comment: @JorgeCampos 1. there is only 1 database, phpfile is connected to localhost. 2. i tried multiple users all same result. all users have access to the tv_genre table because they have matching IDS. 3. i did the select distinct and select id query you just mentioned and they both result the same ids (ofc tv_genre has more, but it has the containing ids in the first output)

Comment: Ok, try after the json_encode `echo json_last_error();` and see if it returns something

Comment: @JorgeCampos echo json_last_error(); returns: "5". Just 5.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks! i solved it! there was a name with this character: "Ö" which couldn't be converted to JSON. i fixed it using a function i will be adding to the main post! Thanks so much.

Comment: So your error is: JSON_ERROR_UTF8 check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php something in your data is smelling

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED! the problem was that my mysql result contained some characters that were unable to convert to JSON use this function to fix it:**

```
function utf8ize($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) {
        return utf8_encode($mixed);
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```