# SELECT FROM query not working with all columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysql-table ("translation") with four columns:
id | text-id | English | Deutsch

I am able to get the data from the column `text-id` with this code:

```
$arr = array();

$query = "SELECT `text-id` FROM `translation`";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}    

header('Content-Type: application/json');  

echo json_encode($arr);
```

But when I try the same with column `English` or `German` I get an empty response.

`mysqli_error()`doesn't show any errors.

Both columns have VARCHAR with 500 characters as data type.

Why is the code mentioned above not working for all columns?

Thanks!

Comment: share your tried code to get help

Comment: tried a `SELECT *`?

Comment: Well, you're *explicitly* selecting only one column.  Did you mean to select more?

Comment: Can you check the column names - you say the column is called `Deutsch` and your trying to access a column `German`

Comment: `$query = "SELECT \`text-id\`, English, Deutsch FROM \`translation\`"` tried this way ?

Comment: What I want is a `SELECT text-id, English FROM translation`. But as soon as column `Deutsch` or `English` is involved in the query, it is not working. May it because of the content in these columns?

Comment: Note you don't have to use a while loop to build the result array yourself, you can just do this: `$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: @JorgeCampos tested right now, unfortunately not working

Comment: I helped a guy a while ago about that. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062563/multiple-inner-join-not-working-in-php#comment83103791_48062563

Comment: @NigelRen: column names are correct.

Comment: that was the comment that helped him solve his issue: " 
Ok, try after the json_encode `echo json_last_error();` and see if it returns something "

Comment: What happens when you try with those columns? Do you get a PHP error or a [mysqli error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Comment: are these reserved words perhaps?  Can you put the ticks around them and try?

Comment: Jorge was right, with `json_last_error()`I get `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`. I will check the solution from the other post

Comment: Thank you guys (and especially Jorge). With the solution from the other post it is working perfectly fine

Comment: Great to know!! Don't forget to upvote both the question and answer from that post! :)